# Laravel 5.3: How to give immediate feedback after sending email

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, feedback

I'm new to Laravel. Please, I need assistance on how to send feedback to site users after sending in their contact form.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\ContactUs;
use App\Mail\ContactForm;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ContactFormController extends Controller
{


    public function sendmail(Request $request)

    {

        $data = $request->all();
        if($data)

        {

            $email = $data['email'];
            ContactUs::where('email', $email);
        }

        Mail::to($email->send(new ContactForm));
    }
}
```

The code above is definitely wrong. I need assistance on how to go about it.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "how to send feedback to site users after sending in their contact form." Are you trying to send them contact form?

Comment: To send them email back in acknowledgment of their feedback.